# I'm trying to connect to a mysql database using PHP but it won't work

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, mysql-error-1045

I've Installed mysql, php, apache using a wamp configuration
Where to access localhost is would be http://localhost:81
the PHP script I'm using is

```
if(mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'exobytes15')) {
mysql_select_db('testDB');
}
else {
echo 'Could not Connect to the database';
 }
```

But this gives me the error

> 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Basic debugging first. What does `echo mysql_error()` say?

Comment: do you have the mysql server started?

Comment: that command gives me the message Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Do a `show grants for root@localhost;` in the mysql monitor (command line mysql prompt). That'd show you if root can access the server. Either you've not explicitly granted root@localhost access rights, or are using the wrong password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you didn't grant root@localhost the necessary rights to access the database or you're providing the wrong password.

Note : granting access to root@`%` does NOT grant access to root@localhost...

Comment: And granting access to `root@\`%\`` is very dangerous, don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have that your database is running, and that the user has access to it.

You can use either use the plain old mysql commandline client for this or phpmyadmin if your wamp stack has that installed.

Answer (score 1):

You're connecting with the wrong password: `Reset the password`

or more likely: you don't have privileges to connect from localhost.
Run the command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@localhost WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Test to see if you can connect.

**Never do:** `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@% WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Because that will put your database server at risk from remote login attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u are running mysql on a port other than the default port.

If it is the case use this:

```
mysql_connect('localhost:PORT', 'root', 'exobytes15')
```

Comment: -1, because in that case there is no server to tell him: `1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: :) he has edited his post. it wasnt there when i added this post.

Comment: It was in the comments 21 mins ago, so I guess you just missed it.

Comment: and i answered 20 minutes ago. suppose concurrent!